# problems with imshow() and rgb2gray() in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Good afternoon,

when running the following code:

```
testImage = double(imread(testfile));
figure; imshow(testImage)
greyTestImage = rgb2gray(testImage);
figure; imshow(greyTestImage)
```

I get unclear and mostly blank Images, I was unable to fx it using the colormap. The following is teh original image and the two resulting figures:

1: [image: original image]

2: [image: result of imshow]

3: [image: image after rgb2gray]

Comment: What is testfile format ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to know the format of the image you are trying to read. To make this sure, I always use the following piece of code in my programs when I want to convert user defined image from unknown format to uint8 grayscale :

```
    % load image
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.*'},'image file');
    fullFilename = [pathname filename];
    % Get image info, read it accordingly
    info = imfinfo(fullFilename);
    if(strcmp('truecolor',info.ColorType))
        I = imread(fullFilename);
        Igray = uint8(rgb2gray(I));
        clear I
    elseif(strcmp('grayscale',info.ColorType))
        Igray = uint8(imread(fullFilename));
    elseif(strcmp('indexed',info.ColorType))
        [I,map] = imread(fullFilename);
        Igray = uint8(ind2gray(I,map));
        clear I map
    else
        error('statPart:FormatImage','Image format error');
    end
    clear info
```

Also, this : `testImage = double(imread(testfile));` won't work if you assume testfile is uint8 and want to convert it to double (in double intensity shall range from 0 to 1). You have to do `testImage = double(imread(testfile)) / 255;`

Hope this help.

Cheers

Comment: This. Alternatively just drop the `double()` and, depending on the originally format of your image, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried converting to 8 bit unsigned integers?

```
testImage = double(imread('PEYXW.jpg'));
figure; imshow(uint8(testImage))
greyTestImage = rgb2gray(uint8(testImage));
figure; imshow(greyTestImage)
```

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an issue with the image you are loading.

The input to the `rgb2gray` function needs to be a 3-channel color image (MxNx3 matrix for the R,G,B channels).

If you use a built-in Matlab sample image, you can effectively do:

```
imdata = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');

figure; imshow(imdata)
```

[image]

Then:

```
test = rgb2gray(imdata);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Matlab provides the function `Im2double` instead of `double` to convert images to double precison:

```
testImage = im2double(imread(testfile));
figure; imshow(testImage)
greyTestImage = rgb2gray(testImage);
figure; imshow(greyTestImage)
```

In double precision, image RGB values are between 0 and 1, for uint8 they range between 0 and 127. When you use the `double` function, all RGB values keep their value, but they are in double precision. This means that any RBG tiple with values >= 1 will result in a double >= 1 and thus produce a white space in your image.
`im2double`actually scales the values to the range [0 1].

Comment: The range of uint8 image, by definition, is [0 255], not [0 127]. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/working-with-8-bit-and-16-bit-images.html#f2-1737