# polyfit in matlab with differrent types of data

Tags: matlab, input, types

When reading an image, the inputs considered for polyfit are different types. one is "uint8" while the other is "double" (their size is the same, <1x384>)
Could you please give me a hint that how I can solve it?

its errors are shown below while I haven't used TIMES in polyfit:

Error using  * 
MTIMES is not fully supported for integer classes. At least one input must be scalar.
To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.

Error in polyfit
p = R(Q'*y);    % Same as p = V\y;

How Can I convert it to unit8? (in other case, its result is not adequate for my script)

Comment: This question requires clarification. Post more details regarding error messages and code.

Comment: You can convert between data types, for instance with `double` or `unit8`.

Comment: Might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924743/problems-with-imshow-and-rgb2gray-in-matlab/17930485#17930485

Comment: Sorry, that was uint8

Comment: Why can't you use double? I would convert to double before processing, and if necessary (and possible) convert a result to uint8

Answer (score 0):

To convert a type double to uint8 you can do the following:

```
b = [1:10]; % <-- type double
a = uint8(b); % <-- convert to uint8

whos a 
  Name      Size                    Bytes  Class

  a         1x1                         1  uint8 array

Grand total is 1 element using 1 bytes
```

To do the reverse:

```
a = uint8([1:10]); % <-- convert to uint8
b = double(a); % <-- type double

whos b
  Name      Size                    Bytes  Class

  b         1x10                       80  double array

Grand total is 10 elements using 80 bytes
```

Type `uint8` variables are unsigned integers (>=0).

Some operations don't work with them, such as `A\b`.

Before attempting your operations with the input images, convert them to double as follows:

```
im_double = double(im_uint8);
```

where `im_uint8` is the original image.